# Google App Maker Widget Validate on Datasource select

Tags: google-app-maker

I have three different fields/textbox widgets, that rely on querying the same data source to be checked to avoid duplication. For reasons, I do not want to turn on the unique/required for those three fields.

I put some code to check for validation. My problem is that when I call the form's validate function, it takes some time till the validation comes back with an error message. However the form's validate returns immediately and allows people to click Submit.

How can I avoid this problem?

1. Block till validation kicks (setTimeout function?)
2. Set a separate invisible field such as working and set the validationError on the field and clear after validations clear? This will probably be a numeric field so that I can wait for all streams in parallel to finish.
3. Final question. is Validate a blocking function as it goes through the fields? I am guessing Yes.

Comment: If this is an insert form for a particular datasource/model why are you not just using the onBeforeCreate event in your model to check for duplicates and return an error if there is?

Comment: I could probably do that but it looses the responsive nature of the form. For example if I use a duplicate value, I wanted the user get immediate response. I might take your advice and code a separate set of routines for server side. Thanks

Comment: Ideally, I guess I could use server side at all times eliminating duplicate logic. Thanks

Comment: Actually I can't. Even though it works, the front end wipes the record so it is a horrible user experience. To type all that, and wiped out with an error message.

Comment: To eliminate this particular problem you could implement a temporary data store or cookies where you store the form entries and if your server script returns errors then recall the previous information and populate the form again.

Comment: I have done one such. It works but I want the API to be sensible. Take the most commonly used path.  Also it seems App Maker does not like restoring it back. I don't remember exactly but I have to try couple different ways to make it work good enough.